# How to send post on click on each button?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have five buttons ( I am entering on page with get)  in jquery mobile and I want on click that button send post to same page with value of pressed button

```
        <div class="ui-grid-b">
            <div data-role="button" id="attack" value="attack" >Attack</div>
            <div data-role="button" id="intercept" value="intercept" >Intercept</div>
            <div data-role="button" id="follow" value="follow">Follow</div>
            <div data-role="button" id="go" value="go">Go</div>
            <div data-role="button" id="send_backup" value="send_backup">Send Backup</div>
        </div>
```

I tried to put this inside form and that every button has type="submit" but it doesn't work.
How to send post on click on each button ?

Comment: What `POST` values do you want to send? Looking at what you're trying to do, you're definitely going about it the wrong way...

Comment: @BenM When I click on attack button I want to send attack, when I click on follow I want to send follow ...

Comment: @BenM To same page where this form is. I tried to put all those buttons in form post="url" and every to be type="submit"

Comment: Why not just run a function when one of the buttons is clicked, and detect it?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution for your problem would be to bind a function to run on the buttons, and then handle the button that was pressed. Something like this:

```
$('.ui-grid-b div[data-role="button"]').click(function() {  
    var button_clicked = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

`button_clicked` will then contain the ID of the button that has just been clicked, so that you can use it however you'd like...

Answer (score 1):

The code will look like this:

```
$('*[data-role="button"]').on('click',function(){

  var dataForm = $('form').serializeArray(); // if you need to send form data
  dataForm.push({name: 'action', value:$(this).attr('id')}); //add your button value

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: window.location.pathname,
    data: dataForm
  })
  .success(function() { alert("success"); })
  .error(function() { alert("error"); });
});
```

You can see the working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/49dA9/1/)

So, you have to use "[data-role="button"]" selector and then send ajax request with ID of your button.

To get form data, you can use [serializeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) and then add also value of just clicked button.

Comment: He said that he needs to "send post to same page with value of pressed button".

Comment: He said that he needs to send form data by clicking one of the buttons. He wants to send data to the same page the form placed on. Why not? He can do something with data on server side and then update somehow the page itself.

Comment: Using the same file destroys the point of using AJAX. If he wants to work with it on a server, he should use a specific file for that.

Comment: Why? Often there are rewrite rules in .htaccess files, for example. Using these rules you can parse query string and select appropriate file to work with.